# Типизация вложенных компонентов

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import { FC, ReactNode } from 'react'

export const ComponentsPopupExampleTypeProblem = () => {
  return (
    <ExternalComponent>
      <ExternalComponent.InternalComponent>
{/*                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Свойство "InternalComponent" не существует в типе "FC<externalComponentProps>*/}
        internalComponent content
      </ExternalComponent.InternalComponent>
    </ExternalComponent>
  )
}

type externalComponentProps = { children: ReactNode }
const ExternalComponent: FC<externalComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return children
}
type internalComponentProps = { children: ReactNode }
const InternalComponent: FC<internalComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return children
}
ExternalComponent.InternalComponent = InternalComponent
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Свойство "InternalComponent" не существует в типе "FC<{ children: ReactNode; }>"
```

```
import { FC, ReactNode } from 'react'

export const ComponentsPopupExampleTypeProblem = () => {
  return (
    <ExternalComponent>
      <ExternalComponent.InternalComponent>
        internalComponent content
      </ExternalComponent.InternalComponent>
    </ExternalComponent>
  )
}

// type ExternalComponentProps = { children: ReactNode }
// const ExternalComponent = ({children}: ExternalComponentProps) => {
//   return children
// }

// type InternalComponentProps = { children: ReactNode }
// const InternalComponent = ({children}: InternalComponentProps) => {
//   return children
// }
// ExternalComponent.InternalComponent = InternalComponent
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Ошибок нет но, если вынести InternalComponent в другой файл или типизировать как FC<...>

type externalComponentProps = { children: ReactNode }
const ExternalComponent: FC<externalComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return children
}

type internalComponentProps = { children: ReactNode }
const InternalComponent: FC<internalComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return children
}
ExternalComponent.InternalComponent = InternalComponent
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Свойство "InternalComponent" не существует в типе "FC<{ children: ReactNode; }>"


/* с GPT аналогичная проблема

Вот пример реализации вложенных компонентов в React с использованием TypeScript:

type AppProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return <div className="app">{children}</div>;
};

type ContentProps = {
  title: string;
};

const Content: React.FC<ContentProps> = ({ title }) => {
  return <h1>{title}</h1>;
};

const ExampleComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <App>
      <App.Content title="Nested Component Example" />
          ^^^^^^^^ Свойство "Content" не существует в типе "FC<AppProps>" 
    </App>
  );
};

export default ExampleComponent;

В этом примере App - это внешний компонент, а Content - вложенный компонент, который может быть использован только внутри App. Обратите внимание, что вложенный компонент Content передается в App как его дочерний элемент с использованием синтаксиса <App.Content />. */
```

Comment: достаточно к типу `FC<externalComponentProps>` добавить свойство с `FC<internalComponentProps>`

Comment: Добрый день @Grundy, можете более точно ответить на примере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В typescript можно расширять типы с помощью [пересечения](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)

Таким образом можно создать новый тип на основе старого с добавлением новых свойств

```
type ExternalComponentType = FC<externalComponentProps> & {
    InternalComponent: FC<internalComponentProps>
}
```

После объявления

```
const ExternalComponent: ExternalComponentType  = ({ children }) => {
    return children
}
```

Ошибки с присваиванием уже не будет

```
ExternalComponent.InternalComponent = InternalComponent
```